# Proving that for all numbers $a, b\in\mathbb{R}$, $\min \{a, b\} \le (a+b)/2$

Tags: inequality

Can anyone help me solve the two cases that are derived from this problem?

Comment: try to find at least one pair of real numbers, for which the inequality doesn't work...

Comment: @V-X: The key, there, is that one is trying to derive a contradiction, yes? If one doesn't keep that in mind, such an approach is a waste of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$$\forall\,a\,,\,b\in\Bbb R\;,\;a<b\implies\frac{a+b}2>\frac{a+a}2\;\ldots$$

Answer (score 8):

Assume $m = \min\{a,b\}> \frac{a+b}{2}$. Then $m+m>\frac{a+b}{2}+\frac{a+b}{2}=a+b\ge m+m$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 5):

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\text{min}(a, b)&\le& a\\
\text{min}(a, b)&\le& b\\
2 \text{min}(a, b)&\le& a + b\\
\text{min}(a, b)&\le& \frac{a + b}{2}.
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: You may as well assume that $a\le b$. (Why is that okay?)

In fact, you should be able to show that $\min\{a,b\}$ is the midpoint of $a,b$ minus half the distance between $a,b$--that is, $$\min\{a,b\}=\frac{a+b}2-\frac{|a-b|}2.$$

Comment: My issue is with assuming that a ≤ b and proving the case. I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: @saurs You have $2$ numbers, $x$ and $y$. *Define* the smaller of the two to be $a$, and the larger to be $b$.

Comment: @saurs: If you've assumed that $a\le b$, then $\min\{a,b\}=???$

Comment: min{a,b} = a. I see your point.

Comment: A user just deleted their [answer](http://i.imgur.com/Tbs0PlN.png) but I was wondering if it can be considered a good approach because of its simplicity?

Comment: @saurs: Certainly. In fact, that's pretty much what I'd recommend.

Answer (score 2):

Let $c=\min\{a,b\}$ and set $A=a-c$, $B=b-c$; observe that $A\ge0$ and $B\ge0$. Then $a=A+c$, $b=B+c$, so
$$
\frac{a+b}{2}=\frac{A+c+B+c}{2}=c+\frac{A+B}{2}\ge c
$$
because $A\ge 0$ and $B\ge 0$.

Answer (score 0):

If $a=b$ you get:
$$min\{a,a\}=\frac{1}{2}2a=a$$
If $a>b$,
$$min\{a,b\}=b$$
So
$$a+b\gt 2b$$
and $a-b\gt0$. Because $a\gt b$ this is true.

Answer (score 0):

Just multiply both sides by two:

$$2 \cdot \min(a, b) < a + b$$

This is necessarily true since either $a$ or $b$ is greater than $\min(a,b)$, and the other is equal to it.